# Накладывание бордеров в ie8

Tags: css, internet-explorer

есть таблица, у неё черные бордеры , а у строк в ней белые горизонтальные бордеры(вертикальные тоже чёрные), в результате получается что левый бордер таблицы пересекается белыми бордерами строк, подскажите есть какое-нибудь решение этого? в остальных браузерах всё нормально

http://screencast.com/t/SFeNoRMmQOGv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете указывать свойства каждой рамки в отдельности. Смотрите документацию и материалы по свойствам:

- border-left
- border-right
- border-top
- border-bottom

Comment: не поможет, тут эффект таков: http://screencast.com/t/323h9dlpa, а без border-collapse: collapse не получится остальное